# MacOs (Catalina) Point-to-Site VPN to Azure Gateway Fails

Tags: vpn, azure, mac, azure-networking, point-to-site-vpn

A few months back, I was able to configure a native point-to-site IKEv2 VPN my Mac (running Catalina) to an Azure Gateway. (The gateway SKU is Standard - not Basic - and I have gone through all the troubleshooting documentation success.)

It involved ensuring:

1. The LocalID matched the subject of the certificate, and
2. The authentication was set to "None" and the correct certificate was still chosen

However, that no longer works, and hasn't for the past few months. Microsoft tech support has been of no help and advised me to either downgrade my MacOS to Mojave or "wait for Apple to fix the problem."

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Noah